# Play/convert DRM protected WMA files in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, drm, wma

I've purchased some DRM protected Windows Media Audio files back in 2006 just to discover they can not be listened today with Windows 10.

Is there a way to use those files today or I can say goodbye to both the files and the money I've spent on them?

What if I reinstall Windows XP? Will this help?

Comment: Try making an XP Virtual Machine (VMware - i use this) or Virtual Box and then recover the Audio files in the XP Machine.

Comment: But will Windows XP help? I've only mentioned WXP because I was using it during the time of purchase and I definitely remember I was able to listen to them on XP

Comment: Since you cannot play on Windows 10, XP is the approach I would take. This is at least worth trying.

Comment: Windows XP at least offers to upgrade DRM components. But looks it is unable to do that as it still can not play the files after clicking the OK button.

Comment: Did the licensing (15 years ago) expire?

Comment: Why should I know? ;) I've paid money to the 7Digital (or Mute Bank directly), got the files, was able to listen to them... but not now. I wasn't warned I've paid for just a temporary license. I think MS has just decided to turn off its DRM infrastructure in terms of expenses optimization. Or they thought I will use the same PC forever and will not need to have the license for any other devices. Bad idea anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know enough about this to help you further.